# How to make cmd read input with spaces as different terms/variables?

Tags: command-line, windows-8.1, batch-file, input

When I want my batch to get input, I use:

```
set /p myvar=Type here:
```

By running the code and inputting something like this with **spaces**:

> This is the input.

Can I get the four words **seperately** assigned as some variables, like

```
1=This
2=is
3=the
4=input.
```

So that I can use these variables ( %1%, %2%, %3%, %4% ) as required?

Or is there any other input command for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative macro approach to array definition:

```bat
@Echo off
rem /* Array macro definition occurs prior to delayed expansion being enabled */
 Set "DefUserArr=Set "#{i}=0"& Set /P "String=Enter #:"& For %%G in (!String!)Do (Set /a "#{i}=!#{i}!+1" & Set "#[!#{i}!]=%%G")"
rem /* Enable delayed expansion in order to expand the macro */
 Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem /* Supply the variable name to be used for the Array group using substring modification as the macro is expanded */
 %DefUserArr:#=Value%
rem /* Access the Group elements using the reference variable */
 Set Value[
rem /* Groups begin from a '1' index and group count is referenced via the Groupname{i} variable */
 Set Value{i}
 Endlocal
```

example input output:

```
C:\Users\tcdou>inputA
Enter Value:one two&<> three^!^!
Value[1]=one
Value[2]=two&<>
Value[3]=three!!
Value{i}=3
```

Of course if your scripting for a user other than yourself, you may want to at least test if input was entered and the 'array' defined prior to using it. below is a slightly more robust version that demonstrates a macro `?ArrDef` that tests this:

```bat
@Echo off & Setlocal DISABLEdelayedexpansion
rem /* Array macro definition occurs prior to delayed expansion being enabled */
 Set "DefUserArr=Set "String="&For %%n in (1 2)Do if %%n==2 ((If /I Not "!Switch!" == "-A" (For /F "Tokens=1,2 Delims==" %%v in ('2^> Nul Set #[')Do Set "%%~v=" & Set "#{i}=0")) & Set /P "String=Enter #:"& For %%G in (!String!)Do (Set /a "#{i}=!#{i}!+1" & Set "#[!#{i}!]=%%~G"))Else Set Switch="
 Set "?ArrDef=For %%n in (1 2)Do if %%n==2 ( If "!#{i}!" == "" ( For %%G in (!Actions!)Do %%~G )Else If "!#{i}!" == "0" ( For %%G in (!Actions!)Do %%~G ))Else Set Actions="
rem /* Enable delayed expansion in order to expand the macro */
 Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem /* Supply the variable name to be used for the Array group using substring modification as the macro is expanded */
:Input1
 %DefUserArr:#=Value%
rem /* test if array defined */
 %?ArrDef:#=Value% "Echo/Inital input required" "Goto :Input1"
rem /* Access the Group elements using the reference variable */
 Set Value[
rem /* Groups begin from a '1' index and group count is referenced via the Groupname{i} variable */
 Set Value{i}
rem /* append to the array using the -A switch */
 %DefUserArr:#=Value%-A
 Set Value[
 Set Value{i}
rem /* Using the DefUserArr macro without the -A switch will remove any preexisting values for the supplied group name. */
:Input3
 %DefUserArr:#=Value%
 %?ArrDef:#=Value% "Echo/New input required" "Goto :Input3"
 Set Value[
 Set Value{i}
 Endlocal & Endlocal
```

Answer (score 2):

```all-ps1
@echo off && title <nul 

title .\%~nx0 && color 0a
cd /d "%~dp0" && mode 50,10
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

>con: echo/ & set /p "_myvar=Enter your Input:"

set "_myvar_0=%_myvar: =" & set/a "_i+=1+0" & set "_myvar_!_i!=%"
<con: ^< nul rem./ && for /l %%l in (0 1 !_i!)do echo=!_myvar_%%~l! 

endlocal & goto=%:EOF
```

---

You can try to use array, with a method posted on  [dostips.com](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6429) /by [@Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini)

The original layout code looks like this:

```all-ps1
set "_myvar=%_myvar: ="&set /a i+=1&set "_myvar[!i!]=%"
```

I prefer replace **`[ ]`** to one simple **`_`**

Also, change **`i+=`** to **`_i+=1+0`**, where no need predefined `set` command: **`set i=0`**

```all-ps1
set "_myvar_0=%_myvar: =" & set/a "_i+=1+0" & set "_myvar_!_i!=%"
```

---

**1.** You can access all occurrences using its delimiter defined by spaces.

```all-ps1
set "%_myvar: ="      ==>      "%_myvar:space="
```

**2.** The method uses a **counter** that where the limit is the total stored in **`!_i!`**.

```all-ps1
set /a _i+=1+0
```

**3.** Using a `for /L` loop you have access to all occurrences, from `0` to the limit **`!_i!`**:

```all-ps1
for /l %%l in (0 1 !_i!)do...
```

**4.** By concatenating the variable `%%l` in the loop with the name assigned to the variable `_myvar_`, you get the values ​​of each occurrence...

```all-ps1
for /l %%l in (0 1 !_i!)do echo=!_myvar_%%~l!
```

---

[image]